# How to group based on ip and aggregate the specific fields in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to group the records based on ip and trying to aggregate the upload and download traffic for the specific ip using scala

```
ip=10.22.3.88 upload =470 download =308
ip=10.22.3.89 upload =526 download =603
ip=10.22.3.88 upload =542 download =603
ip=10.22.3.90 upload =292 download =235
ip=10.22.3.90 upload =210 download =653
ip=10.22.3.88 upload =210 download =653
```

Can anyone please help me out regarding the same ...

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: Nope. I'm a newbie to Scala.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. If you try it yourself first and post an actual code, people will be able to help you better. As for your current question, you can solve a simpler problem first, just create a collection of objects in your code and see if you can find out how to group them using Scala collection API. This way you split the problem in two parts (parsing to objects, grouping objects).

Comment: @dev007 can you tell me how should the final output will look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can understand you want total `upload` and `download` traffic after grouping `IP`. Assuming that your above data is stored in a `String`. You can first map each line to a `case Class` and then do grouping based on your `IP`. after that you need to add the `upload` and `download` traffic for that grouped IP. Please find the below code for this.

```
//Create a case class which replicates your incoming data
case class Tracker(IP: String, upload: Double, dowload: Double)

//assuming you have data as a string and each record in a new line 
val data =
      """ip=10.22.3.88 upload =470 download =308
        |ip=10.22.3.89 upload =526 download =603
        |ip=10.22.3.88 upload =542 download =603
        |ip=10.22.3.90 upload =292 download =235
        |ip=10.22.3.90 upload =210 download =653
        |ip=10.22.3.88 upload =210 download =653"""

   //process data line by line and map to Tracker class
    val lst = data.split("\n").map(x => {
      val array = x.split("=")
      Tracker(array(1).split(" ")(0).trim,
        array(2).split(" ")(0).trim.toDouble,
        array(3).split(" ")(0).trim.toDouble)
    })

   //finally group by IP and then add upload and download traffic for grouped IP
    val result = lst.groupBy(_.IP)
      .map(x =>
        (x._1,
          x._2.map(_.upload).sum,
          x._2.map(_.dowload).sum))

    print(result)
    //output
    //List((10.22.3.90,502.0,888.0), (10.22.3.89,526.0,603.0), (10.22.3.88,1222.0,1564.0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me to understand and it worked out for me.

Comment: Great that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to group the above structure based on ip addresses.

So for making our implementation easier, I will be storing the following data in a structure, like this:-

```
case class IpAddress(ip:String,
                     upload: String,
                     download: String)

val ipAddress1 = IpAddress("10.22.3.88", "470", "308")
val ipAddress2 = IpAddress("10.22.3.89", "526", "603")
val ipAddress3 = IpAddress("10.22.3.88", "542", "603")
val ipAddress4 = IpAddress("10.22.3.90", "292", "235")
val ipAddress5 = IpAddress("10.22.3.90", "210", "653")
val ipAddress6 = IpAddress("10.22.3.88", "210", "653")

val listIpAddress = Seq(ipAddress1, ipAddress2, ipAddress3, ipAddress4, ipAddress5, ipAddress6)
```

I took a case class called IpAddress and created 6 structures as provided as input values.

After that I am creating a sequence to store all of my 6 structures. If you don't know what case class and Seq is, then I suggest to read up on them.

Now the following implementation would give you a map of `key -> value`,  where the key will be ip address and the value will be a sequence of IpAddress structures, which have common ip address.

```
val ipMap = listIpAddress.groupBy(_.ip).map { ipValue =>
   ipValue._1 -> ipValue._2
}
```

If you have any doubts, please put it in the comments below.

Hope this helps!